# SQL Service Broker - The server principal "sa" is not able to access

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I am getting a permission error when trying to send a message from my database.

I enamble the proker service:

```
-- Enable Broker on Initiator
ALTER DATABASE A-DB SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
ALTER DATABASE A-DB SET ENABLE_BROKER;
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::A-DB TO [sa];
ALTER DATABASE A-DB SET TRUSTWORTHY ON;
ALTER DATABASE A-DB SET MULTI_USER;
GO
```

I then create the queues and all that...

When I attempt to send a message, I am seeing the following error in sys.transmission_queue:

> An exception occurred while enqueueing a message in the target queue.
>   Error: 916, State: 3. The server principal "sa" is not able to access
>   the database "MYDBNAME" under the current security context.

(Where MYDBNAME is the name of the database we're using)

I THINK the error is caused by this line:

> ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::A-DB TO [sa];

That might be a bad thing. But, can I alter the authorisation to put it back to what ever it was? I thought it would be 'dbo' but that's not right. Should it be set to who ever created the database?

Comment: Is the conversation cross DB (initiator in one db, target in another? If yes, can you check in the *other* DB if `EXECUTE AS USER 'dbo'` succeeds? I expect it to fail, and then you need to `ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::[MYDBNAME] TO [sa];`.

Comment: Getting same error myself.  In my case both services are in same db, but activated sp on my target queue calls a sp which errors because it includes a join to the [MYDBNAME].  Any luck?  Did Remus' solution work?

Answer (score 7):

Exception - Error: 916, State: 3. The server principal "\" is not able to access the database "" under the current security context.

Error: 916, State: 3. The server principal 'sa' is not able to access the database 'xxx' under the current security context.

Resolution - Execute 'ALTER DATABASE ... SET TRUSTWORTHY ON' command.
[technet link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187861.aspx)

> Because a database that is attached to an instance of SQL Server
>   cannot be immediately trusted, the database is not allowed to access
>   resources beyond the scope of the database until the database is
>   explicitly marked trustworthy.

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET TRUSTWORTHY ON
```

In my case, both initiator and target service were in the same db, but it was a join to an outer db that caused this error.  The Alter should be written for the db in which Svc Broker is enabled.

Comment: Because I use SSDT. I set "Database Settings" - "Miscellaneous" - "Server Broker options:" EnableBroker

Answer (score 0):

Because a database is a server-level object, it needs to be owned by a server-level principal. So, you need to provide a login to own the database. As to which login, I typically choose sa but it can be your login or that of any other individual's login.